# Calculate items of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to merge some multidimension arrays and calculate the values of their items. For example :

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nr_colete] => 6
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [nr_colete] => 22
                )
        )
)
```

> I want to get a solution to combine them and get a result such as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [nr_colete] => 6 + 22
        )
)
```

Is there a native php function to help me get this result ? I try to found one.

Comment: No predefined PHP function for that which generate result in single line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No native function which will do that directly.But you can use `array_column()` and `array_sum()` two native function to get your desired result.

Check below code:-

```
$final_array[0]['nr_colete'] = array_sum(array_column(array_column($array,0),'nr_colete'));
print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/873338

Reference:-

[array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

[array_sum()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: Yes ! It works very fine and is the result that i expected for. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @SoptareanuAlex  lad to help you :):)

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of one single php native function to do this, but you can do it very simply using a foreach loop.

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($array AS $k => $value) {
    $sum += $value[0]['nr_colete'];
}
```

[Here is the code in action](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4d7975e848f5f645b44f85005dace31183185428)